# Tool to visualize code flow in Java?

Tags: java, code-analysis

I'm inspired by the [C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153074/tool-to-visualise-code-flow-cc) question for a code flow visualization tool.

Is there such a thing for Java servlets or applications?

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. It's a valid question.

And this is the answer: findtheflow.io

Answer (score 11):

Maybe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> in Eclipse / IntelliJ IDEA ? (albo present in NB somewhere)
Or "data flow from/to" in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: "Call Hierarchy", thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

http://code.google.com/p/jtracert/ was discontinued. The link for new project is:
https://github.com/bedrin/jsonde

Comment: domain jsonde.com is dead. Last files for jsonde are from 2011 http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsonde/files/

Answer (score 3):

If found that [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) works for Java also.

Answer (score 2):

Source Navigator says it does Java, though I've only ever used it for C/C++ myself.
http://developer.berlios.de/projects/sourcenav

Answer (score 1):

[JBuilder](http://www.codegear.com/products/jbuilder)'s UML view goes some of the way

Answer (score 1):

IBM has an old (2004) [structure analysis tool](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/sa4j) that does some visualization of Java code.

[Netbeans'](http://www.netbeans.org/) UML does a decent job reverse engineering the code too.

Comment: Do you know off hand what UML models NetBeans can reverse engineer? I've only reversed engineered into Class diagrams, but I'm wondering if it can also be used to go from code into sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this and is AWESOME for automatic sequence diagram generation

https://github.com/bedrin/jsonde

Answer (score 1):

HandyEdit has made a plugin that does exactly this: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=3739

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like [Jeliot](http://cs.joensuu.fi/jeliot/) and [jGrasp](http://www.jgrasp.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

In UML 2 there are two basic categories of diagrams: structure diagrams and behavior diagrams. Every UML diagram belongs to one these two diagram categories. The purpose of structure diagrams is to show the static structure of the system being modeled. They include the class, component, and or object diagrams. Behavioral diagrams, on the other hand, show the dynamic behavior between the objects in the system, including things like their methods, collaborations, and activities. Example behavior diagrams are activity, use case, and sequence diagrams.

Here, my understanding is that the OP is asking for a tool to visualize **code flow** (this is the title of the question), i.e. dynamic behavior. A perfect diagram for this would be the sequence diagram.

But, AFAIK, neither UML reverse engineering tools nor Doxygen can figure out such diagrams from sources. These tools know how to generate structure diagrams (e.g. class diagram), but not behavior diagrams (this would require execution). So these tools doesn't answer the question (even for C++).

IMO, to visualize the code flow, you'll have to look at the call hierarchy as someone pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite one was [Creole](http://www.thechiselgroup.com/creole). Unfortunately last update was made on August 10, 2007... but still it is worth trying.

Another option, but more for the architecture visualization than code flow, is Structure101, which is a great tool and absolutely worth to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Onyem JTracer](http://www.onyem.com) The tool automatically generates execution flow diagrams by analysis of your java program. I have used it with a relatively large codebase as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Heatlamp](http://www.jmolly.com/heatlamp) will visualize running Java code. It can also visualize Java stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Zeta Code](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/296054304/zeta-code) seeks to do this.