# Visualizing Java project

Tags: java, android

I have been tasked with porting a large Java codebase to the Android platform.  The project makes extensive use of AWT which isn't' supported on Android.

I'm looking for a tool that lets me visualize all of the classes in the project.  I'd like to be able to see all of the relationships between classes so that I can get a good idea of where to start the port.

If you have any suggestions that would help in this task I'd like to hear about them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use Structure101 almost daily to visualize and understand our code base. A great tool and quite reasonably priced too.

This question has been touched at StackOverflow many times before and here are some links:

- [Is there some tool to visualize java class hierarchies and relations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344/is-there-some-tool-to-visualize-java-class-heirarchies-and-relations)
- [Tool to visualize code flow in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153414/tool-to-visualize-code-flow-in-java)
- [Recommended Eclipse plugins to generate UML from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)
- [Good free UML tool for Java/Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse)

IntelliJ IDEA also has some tools to help, like Graphical Navigator in IDEA 8 and [Code Navigator plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=3202).

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has an OK reverse engineering tool which spits out a heaps of UML.  I haven't used it in a while, but when I did it was a tad buggy.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Eclipse plugin called Creole which you could also try. http://www.thechiselgroup.com/creole