# What is a good way to approach legacy code and lay it so its easier to analyze and modify

Tags: procedural-programming

With older languages (non-OO Ex. Alpha Basic +) What is a good way to layout the code when reading threw it so your not constantly having to jump back and forth? I find myself having a hard time seeing the big picture of some programs and how there functioning, making it even harder to implement whatever change I need to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For procedural language, can you try few code analyzer tool. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153074/tool-to-visualise-code-flow-c-c) question can be a pointer. In case you need some customized flow, a simple tool with perl/python would also help you. These tools will definitely help in ease of understanding "high" level picture of the system/subsystem.
HTH!